# Get only non-zero sub arrays from a N dimensional Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `numpy` `array` `'arr'` that is of `shape (1756020, 28, 28, 4)`. 
Basically `'arr'` has `1756020` small arrays of `shape (28,28,4)`. Out of the `1756020` arrays `967210` are 'all zero' and `788810` has all non-zero values. I want to remove all the `967210` 'all zero' small arrays. I wrote a if else loop using the condition `arr[i]==0.any()` but it takes a lot of time. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Try `arr[(arr!=0).any(axis=(1,2,3))]`.

Comment: [numpy.count_nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html#numpy.count_nonzero) ?

Comment: arr.any(axis(1,2,3)) might be more effective, because the first nonzero value is enough to keep it, counting the total number is not needed

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? Feel free to accept one (tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 6):

One way to vectorise your logic is to use [`numpy.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) with a tuple argument for `axis` containing non-tested dimensions.

```
# set up 4d array of ones
A = np.ones((5, 3, 3, 4))

# make second of shape (3, 3, 4) = 0
A[1] = 0  # or A[1, ...] = 0; or A[1, :, :, :] = 0

# find out which are non-zero
res = np.any(A, axis=(1, 2, 3))

print(res)

[True False True True True]
```

This feature is available in `numpy` v0.17 upwards. As per the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.any.html):

> **axis** : *None or int or tuple of ints, optional*
>
> If this is a tuple of ints, a reduction is performed on multiple axes,
>   instead of a single axis or all the axes as before.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, This is pretty much *exactly* what I have. The difference being I'm identifying the zero arrays. There's no fundamental difference, though. Do you believe there is?

Comment: I think the problem with arr != 0 is that it creates one new huge array. It needs about 5 gbyte (or whatever) memory. Maybe also A == 0 is unnecessary, why not just res = np.any(A, axis=(1, 2, 3))?

Comment: Minor point: `A[1, :, :, :] = 0` is just equivalent to `A[1] = 0` - there's no need to specify the slices for the trailing axes (either explicitly or using ellipses).

Comment: @AnttiA, Timing the 3 options (A==0, A!=0, just A), there isn't much difference. I don't *think* you'll find any memory benefit either. Does your testing suggest something else?

Comment: @AlexRiley, Thanks - appreciated, I put all 3 up for good order.

Comment: Time difference  in  my laptop: ok = np.any(arr2, axis=1): 0.64 s, ok = np.any(arr2 != 0, axis=1): 95 s. Think what happen there, in latter version a new 1756020*28*28*4 boolean array is created before comparision. With only any(arr2), it stops to first non-zero element, so it needs (in my example) to compare only 1756020 values.

Comment: @AnttiA, Fair enough, I trust your benchmarking (but, as you say, version dependent), updated.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small test script with the size you mentioned. With my computer, array creation (memory error if floats, thats why booleans) and selection are slow, but finding zeros seems to be rather fast:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = np.ones((1756020, 28, 28, 4), dtype=bool)
    for i in range(0,1756020,2):
        arr[i] = 0
    print(arr[:5])
    s = arr.shape
    t0 = time.time()
    arr2 = arr.reshape((s[0], np.prod(s[1:])))
    ok = np.any(arr2, axis=1)
    print(time.time()-t0)
    arr_clean = arr2[ok]
    print(time.time()-t0)
    arr_clean = arr_clean.reshape((np.sum(ok), *s[1:]))
    print(time.time()-t0)
    print('end')
```

Output:

0.4846000671386719 # Find of zeros is fast

29.750200271606445 # Removing zeros is slow

29.797000408172607 # Reshape to original shapes [1:] is fast